# How to upside down the result rows of a select statment in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I can select a list of rows from a table. but I want to show them by swapping upside down. 
Explaination:

```
with table1 as
(
    select 1 ID, 'txt1' value from dual
    union all
    select 2, 'txt2' from dual
    union all
     select 7, 'txt7' from dual
        union all
     select 5, 'txt5' from dual
        union all
     select 3, 'txt3' from dual
)
select * from table1;
```

in above query I can obtain following result

```
ID     |    VALUE
------------------
1         txt1
2         txt2
7         txt7
5         txt5
3         txt3
```

but I want to show them as follows

```
ID     |    VALUE
------------------
3         txt3
5         txt5
7         txt7
2         txt2
1         txt1
```

How to do that?

Comment: As there's no *order* in which rows are stored in a table, you can `ORDER BY` something to get it in one order, or `ORDER BY DESC` to get it upside down. If there's no indicator which tells you *how* to sort those values, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to add a computed column to your set of union queries, then order by that column:

```
WITH table1 AS (
    SELECT 1 ID, 'txt1' value, 1 AS position FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'txt2', 2 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'txt7', 3 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'txt5', 4 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'txt3', 5 FROM dual
)

SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY pos DESC;
```

Note that there is no internal order to a SQL table in general.  Actually, even the current ordering you are observing is not necessarily guaranteed by Oracle.  If you expect a certain order in a result set, you need to impose it via a `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: GROUP BY or ORDER BY ?

Comment: @Nwn Sorry, I meant `ORDER BY`.  The jist of my answer is that if you need to order your result set, then you should find one or more columns which can be used to impose this ordering.

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
with table1 as
(
    select 1 ID, 'txt1' value from dual
    union all
    select 2, 'txt2' from dual
    union all
     select 7, 'txt7' from dual
        union all
     select 5, 'txt5' from dual
        union all
     select 3, 'txt3' from dual
)
select * from table1 order by rownum desc;
```

Actually this is not working for this perticular example. but it is working for normal table.

Comment: This *doesn't* work.  `order by rownum`?  I understand the answer, but not the upvote.